# PHP Unit test Error - PHPUnit_Util_DeprecatedFeature_Logger

Tags: php, unit-testing, web, phpunit, composer-php

I have installed PHPUnit with the composer. I have below line in composer.json

```
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.3"
},
```

When I run my test case I am getting below error. I have searched for this error but I could not find possible related solutions in web:

```
        Vishal@VISHAL-PC c:\xampp\htdocs\V4\test\Core

        phpunit ResponseTest 


        PHPUnit 4.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.


       Fatal error: Class PHPUnit_Util_DeprecatedFeature_Logger contains 1 abstract met
       hod and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (
      PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\
      DeprecatedFeature\Logger.php on line 201
```

I have no clue where this is coming from. Any suggestions, link or comment will be much appreciated guys.

Comment: Make sure this file C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\DeprecatedFeature\Logger.php has an abstract method and if so, try changing to another version closer to 4.3.5.

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep ! Seemed like it didn't have an abstract method in Loger.php and have added one. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHPUnit_Util_DeprecatedFeature_Logger` class was removed in PHPUnit 4.2. If your installation of PHPUnit 4.3 tries to use that class this means that you're installation is messed up somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You still continue to run your phpunit from previously installed location. To run it from composer add following allias to your .bashrc file

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc

alias phpunit="/{path_to_project}/vendor/bin/phpunit"
```